# How to divide a RDD into multiple RDDs according to every father RDD's element

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to find a way to divide a fatherRDD into multiple RDDs accordingly to every fatherRDD's element.

For example, the elements of fatherRDD have lots of lists. I want to split this fatherRDD into lots of small RDD based on every element. In other words, if there are n elements in the fatherRDD, I want to get n RDDs.

Two days ago, I wrote a function like this:

```
def splitRDD(rdd1:RDD[List[(String, String)]]):List[RDD[(String, String)]] ={
   var list = List[RDD[(String, String)]] ()
   //println(rdd1.take(1).apply(0).apply(0)._1)
   rdd1.foreach(x =>{
      list = sc.makeRDD(x)::list
   }) 
   list    
}
```

I think the wrong is I can not use `sc.makeRDD(x)` here. So how to divide a RDD into multiple RDDs according to every father RDD's element?

Comment: What you are trying to obtain by creating multiple RDDs. ?

Comment: @Suresh i want to obtain lots of RDDs ,the element of these RDDs is a list

Comment: @Suresh , In other words, if fatherRDD have n elements(List type),i want to obtain n childRDD

Comment: @tttwelve What is the benefit of creating multiple rdds here? Please let us know so that we can provide a different approach this.

Comment: can you try `val list = fatherRDD.collect` and then `list.map{sc.parallelize(_)}` you will get `List[RDD]` this will be  better to work and also keep track of RDDs

Comment: @RakeshRakshit because i want to obtain many childRDD to groupbykey or reducebykey continually

Comment: @AkashSethi But the number of fatherRDD's elements is too large to filter. i want  if fatherRDD have n elements(List type),i want to obtain n childRDD

Comment: @tttwelve just updated comment take a look

Comment: @AkashSethi oh ,i will trying to this way ,thank you~

Comment: @tttwelve can i post the same as answer i need some reputation if you allow

Comment: @AkashSethi ok，what can i do for you ? thanks~

Comment: @AkashSethi hi,the way you suggested yesterday is useful ,but i also have a question . After val list = fatherRDD.collect , it will return a scala array in a single node which contain driver program. meanwhile , my data is too large ,i worry the single node will runs out of resources and crashes

Comment: yes, collect will return all the data to driver memory what do you want to do with so many RDDs as it is not a good idea to create large number of rdds

Comment: @AkashSethi,yes it is not a good idea to create large number of rdds,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description it should look like this:

```
def splitRDD(rdd1:RDD[List[(String, String)]]):List[RDD[(String, String)]] =  rdd1.collect().toList.map(x => makeRdd(x))

def makeRdd(ls:List[(String,String)]): RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(ls)
```

Try this out for your data. is that what you want ?

Comment: hi,  i also have a question . After  rdd1.fatherRDD.collect , it will return a scala array in a single node which contain driver program. meanwhile , my data is too large ,i worry the single node will runs out of resources and crashes.